# How can i count the total logged in time in PHP?

Tags: php, session, time, authentication

I need to make a website for school with PHP and in this website i need to count how long a person is logged in.

For example you are logged in for 1 minute and you go to another page then you need to see in the top of the page

Logged in for : 3 minuntes 20 secondes

if you refresh the page or go to another one the time needs to be refreshed and show the total amount of time you are logged in

I searched up allot of things but i couldn't find what i was looking for.

i tried this

```
<li>Logged in for : <?php echo $_SESSION['last_login'] ?? ''; ?></li>
```

but it shows a couple of numbers and nothing else

Comment: If I am logged in for 1 minute, WHY would the next page tell me `Logged in for : 3 minuntes 20 secondes`

Comment: What is in the `$_SESSION['last_login']` field? In other words, what do you set that to?

Comment: You would be better to start by showing us the script that does the User Login

Answer (score 4):

I would store their login time when they log in:

```
$_SESSION["login_time"] = time();
```

And then calculate the elapsed time for every page load:

```
$time_logged_in = time() - $_SESSION["login_time"];
$minutes_logged_in = floor($time_logged_in / 60);
$seconds_logged_in = $time_logged_in % 60;
$display_session_time = "Logged in for {$minutes_logged_in} minute(s) and {$seconds_logged_in} seconds.";
```

Answer (score 1):

In your login code set session time when user was logged in.

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = time();
```

and in your show code

```
$diffTime = time() - $_SESSION['logged_in'];

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $diffTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `time()` function to calculate the login time. On the login success page :

```
$_SESSION['startTime'] = time();
```

On the remaining page where the time is showed :

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['startTime']) && is_int($_SESSION['startTime'])){ // if the cookie exists:
    echo echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - $_SESSION['startTime']);
}
```